# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var grid = [];
    for (var i = 0;i < 6;i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        grid[i] = [];
    }

    //Checking function(how many bombs near)
    function check(cx,cy)
    {
        var numb = 0;
        if (grid[cx][cy - 1] == "B") numb++;
        if (grid[cx][cy + 1] == "B") numb++;
        if (grid[cx - 1][cy] == "B") numb++;
        if (grid[cx + 1][cy] == "B") numb++;
        if (grid[cx - 1][cy - 1] == "B") numb++;
        if (grid[cx + 1][cy - 1] == "B") numb++;
        if (grid[cx - 1][cy + 1] == "B") numb++;
        if (grid[cx + 1][cy + 1] == "B") numb++;

        return numb;
    }**
```

it gives me an error when i try to check every position that contains cx + or - 1, i tried to make the array in other ways but it didn't help. I try to make a minesweeper game, so here i check how many bombs are near each given idex

Comment: Can you please add a little bit of context to this question to help the readers understand what you're trying to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your function

when call check(0,0)

```
if (grid[cx][cy - 1] == "B") numb++;
```

> grid[0][0-1]=

0-1=?!

Comment: Yeah, i wish i could know how to fix it, or how i could make it in another way

Answer (score 0):

To prevent using indices of an array which have no array or value, you could use a function and hand over the array and indices and return `true`, if the value is `'B'`, otherwise `false`.

The check takes plase with [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) and a guard operator ([logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_())) which breaks on `false` and continues for `true` and checks then the value.

```
function checkB(array, i, j) {
    return i in array && array[i][j] === 'B';
}

// call
if (checkB(grid, cx, cy - 1)) numb++;
```

Comment: i try to make a minesweeper game, and here i check how many bombs are near each index